# WP custom nav menu problem

Tags: menus

I've got a problem with a piece of code from a previous developer's website. He appears to have created a custom nav menu using the code from these sources:

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935423/how-do-i-generate-a-custom-menu-sub-menu-system-using-wp-get-nav-menu-items-in-w)
[source2](https://gist.github.com/hitautodestruct/4345363)

Now the code works fine with WP's menu system, that is until you try to add a third level sub-menu: e.g:

Destinations (top) > Europe > France

Adding anything below Europe will result in this:

[image]

So anything below or the child of Europe disappears and it's sibling "Asia" pops out of it's parent (destination) into the top level. I've looked for other sources and answers to this question but I've found none. I've pasted the code I'm using at the moment and it seems (I've checked a few times) nearly identical to the above source, I'm missing something here, could anyone help?

```
    <div class='navigation'>
      <?php
            $menu_name = 'header_menu';
            $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name]);
            $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC'      ) );
                              ?>

        <nav>
            <ul class="main-nav nav nav-justified">
        <?php
            $count = 0;
            $submenu = false;

            foreach( (array) $menuitems as $item ):
                // get page id from using menu item object id
                    $id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
                // set up a page object to retrieve page data
                    $page = get_page( $id );
                    $link = get_page_link( $id );

                // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
                        if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):

                // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
                        $parent_id = $item->ID;
                                ?>

                        <li class="item">
                            <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title">
                            <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>

                                <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <div class='row'>

                                <?php endif; ?>


                                <?php // Sub menu ?>
                                    <div class='col-md-12'>
                                        <li class="item">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"class="title">
                                                        <!--<div class='nav-item-featured' style='background-image:url(<?php echo $url; ?>);'></div>-->
                                                        <?php //$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id) ); ?>
                                                        <div class='title'><strong><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></strong></div>
                                             </a>
                                         </li>

                                    </div>


                                        <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
                                        </div>
                                        </ul>
                                        <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
                                </li>                           
                                <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

                            <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>

                            </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Menus architecture is totally not meant to be used in this way. I would strongly advise to scrap this and do proper `wp_nav_menu()` implementation instead.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling this code seemed odd considering how menus are normally less troublesome. I'll use wp_nav_menu instead then.

Comment: @steveBeeSmart I wrote that code, if [you can tell me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935423/how-do-i-generate-a-custom-menu-sub-menu-system-using-wp-get-nav-menu-items-in-w/11948374#11948374) how to customise the html that `wp_nav_menu()` is producing I'll take down that code and burn it :)

Comment: @Rarst wp_nav_menu() is very limited to what it can do, even if you extend `Walker_Nav_Menu()`. The above will be less code and more efficient for customization.

Comment: @RickyB I disagree, Walkers can be _unfriendly_ to code, but they are flexible and can support very elaborate solutions. Snippet in question is just disorganized tag soup.

Comment: @Rarst Thats Ok. But until you need a truly customized unorthodox menu, you will realize how painful it is to extend all the Walker_Nav_Menu methods. The tag soup above is bad but is still better than a superfluous & perplexing class extension, if that's what you mean by **flexible**.